# Does anybody know what Queued status means in terms of Pipeline Runs in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure

I'm facing a problem concerning a Pipeline run in Azure Data Factory.

The run is in Queued status and I don't know why is in this status and not running if there isn't any other pipeline running.

I don't know what Queued status means in terms of Pipeline runs in Azure Data Factory.

Does anybody know it?

Comment: This question on SO may shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52729007/1265167

Comment: Also, FYI the UI for the copy activity I have is showing Queued, but I can see the SQL table sink slowly filling up with data ....